# Emacs and company autocompletion. Add a header directory globally

Tags: emacs, completion

I'm trying to add a header files path to company-mode but I can't do it. I did it with flycheck as follow:

```
(defun include-paths ()
   (setq flycheck-clang-include-path (list (expand-file-name "../include"))))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'include-paths)
```

Is there a similar way to do it with company-mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using [company-c-headers](https://github.com/randomphrase/company-c-headers).

Almost verbatim from their README file, you can use `M-x customize-groups`, `company-c-headers` to modify the search directories.

Alternatively, you can bind the company-c-headers-path-system and company-c-headers-path-user variables to functions which return the corresponding paths. For example, if you are using EDE, you can use the following:

```
(defun ede-object-system-include-path ()
  "Return the system include path for the current buffer."
  (when ede-object
    (ede-system-include-path ede-object)))

(setq company-c-headers-path-system 'ede-object-system-include-path)
```

[Source](https://github.com/randomphrase/company-c-headers)

Comment: Is company-c-headers necessary? I thought it is a package to autocomplete c headers. Isn't possible to setup this path without using this package?

Comment: I'd recommend that you read up more on how company-mode works.  It's really a framework for writing autocompletion backends.  While it does ship with some very good ones out of the box, adding additional backends can improve functionality.  I think it uses clang as a backend for C and C++ by default, but for include file completion company-c-headers is needed.

For more information: http://company-mode.github.io/

Comment: Emacs is quite overwhelming, but I've found it to be a lot of fun!  Good luck and happy hacking :)